# React print this.props only when value is not null

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have two simple React classes

*Dashboard (parent)*

```
class UserDashboardPage extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("UserDashboardPage")
    console.log(this.props.users)
    return (
      <div>
        <UserInfoComponent user={this.props.users} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// map Users from store to Props
function mapStateToProps({ users }) {
  return { users };
}
```

*UserInfoComponent (child)*

```
export class UserInfoComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("UserInfoComponent")
    console.log(this.props.user)
    return (
      <h2>{this.props.user.firstName}</h2>
    );
  }
}
```

and the problem I am having is that I want to print the `this.props.user.firstName` in the UserInfoComponent but the value is initially null and then the component does not re-render when the value gets the data.

*userReducers*

```
const initialState = { data: [], user: null };

const UserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER :
      return {
        data: [action.user, ...state.data],
      };
    case UPDATE_USER :
      return {
        user: action.user,
      };
    case LOGIN_USER: {
      const user = (action.response.statusCode === 200) ? action.response.user : null;

      console.log(user);

      return {
        user,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[Example of how the data changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99wZw.png)

Comment: Can you show your reducer function? most cases this occur due to a immutability problem

Comment: @Robsonsjre Just updated. Is what what you needed?

Comment: does it throw any console errors? Since you're accessing `firstName` on a null object in `UserInfoComponent`

Comment: @AbhishekNair no, it just doesn't print the `firstName`. The console is the link I shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer just change const `initialState = { data: [], user: null }` to `const initialState = { data: [], user: {} };` By making the intial state of user an empty object you can avoid any issues with `this.props.user['property']` causing a cannot read property of undefined error.

Furthermore you should probably show something else if initially user is an empty object. If you are doing an AJAX request to get the user info then think about maybe doing a loading component. You would just need to add a new state to your reducer like so:

```
const initialState = { data: [], user: {}, loading: true };
```

and then once you get the user info back, assuming thats from login user, you can have the reducer set `loading: false` also you should either be using Object.assign or the `...` operator to avoid mutating the original state. see http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html. Updates so your reducers would look like this

```
const UserReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER :
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [action.user, ...state.data],
      };
    case UPDATE_USER :
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
      };
    case LOGIN_USER: {
      const user = (action.response.statusCode === 200) ? action.response.user : null;

      console.log(user);

      return {
        ...state,
        user,
        loading: false
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and then in your UserDashboard component

```
class UserDashboardPage extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("UserDashboardPage")
    console.log(this.props.users)

    const content = this.props.loading ? '....loading' : <UserInfoComponent user={this.props.users} />;
    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this will make sure it shows loading and then once the user loads it will show the users information.

Comment: that would work, but it turns out my problem was a client and server reducers mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you wanted to render one `UserInfoComponent` for each entry in the `users` property.

If `users` is an array of `user` objects you might want to do

```
{ users.map((user) => (<UserInfoComponent user={user} />) }
```

Otherwise, either provide an empty object as default value for `users` (by using `defaultProps`) or check for existence of a `users` value in your `mapStateToProps` function.